# How to bind to a child property and still get updates?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, entity-framework-4

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE parent
( 
   id           NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
   name         VARCHAR2(15 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   child_id     NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
   primary key (id) 
); 

CREATE TABLE child
( 
   id           NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL, 
   name         VARCHAR2(15 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
   primary key (id) 
); 

ALTER TABLE parent 
ADD constraint foreign key (child_id) references child;
```

And the following XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="aDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=NAME}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CHILD.NAME}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The data is bound like this:

```
using(var context = new Entities())
{
    this.aDataGrid.ItemsSource = context.Parent.ToList();
}
```

When I:

```
var parent = this.aDataGrid.SelectedItem as Parent;
parent.Name = anotherName;
```

The first cell is updated in the DataGrid immediately. But when I:

```
var parent = this.aDataGrid.SelectedItem as Parent;
parent.Child = anotherChild;
```

it doesn't update the second cell automatically.

How to correct this? What I am missing?

Comment: Show where you create and bind the collection.   Show the classes for Parent and Child.

Comment: @BalamBalam I included the requested code

Comment: No you did not include the requested code.  Show the classes for Parent and Child.

Comment: @BalamBalam They are generated by the Entity Framework based on the above Oracle Tables.

Comment: Oh, you should include that detail in the question and you should tag it with EntityFramework.  Still need to see those classes.  Do they implement iNotifyPropertychanged.

Comment: @BalamBalam No, there is no INotifyPropertyChanged in the whole solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to impliment INotifyPropertyChanged and RaisePropertyChanged "Child" in the setter of your Child property?  This should flag the binding that it needs to update - without this the binding doesnt know the propety has changed.
If you parent/child objects are EF generated then you may want to google "EF and MVVM" for some ideas on how to glue those objects to your UI view - including but not limited to triggering property change updates.

Comment: No, there is no `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the whole solution, the code was generated by EF4, can I alter it?

Comment: Im not familiar with EF generated code but my guess is it generates a garden all .NET property and not something tailered to WPF binding.  You can probably add this over the top of generated code using partial class but normally you would have a ViewModel wrapper to your EF object as glue between your EF object (model) and your UI xaml (view) ala MVVM.  Typically its the view model that impliments INotifyPropertyChange.

Answer (score 0):

I could force the DataGrid to load the new values using

```
var itemsSource = this.aDataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<Parent>;
this.aDataGrid.ItemsSource = itemsSource.ToList();
```

But it doesn't seem right.
I just discovered that the same can be achieved with

```
this.aDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

But I still think that must be a better way